# Excel changes simple data into formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

I have a large document that changes anything I type into a formula. This is an acquired workbook, not one I created. I have no idea how to fix this. As a result, data entry has taken the step of inserting ' before any data, which will not allow me to perform calculations.

Here's an example screenshot. In this example, I did not type the = sign, I only typed 5:15. After clicking enter the = sign appears.

[image]

I typed 5:15 into cell H7, hit "Enter" then I get a circular reference.

Comment: In the example shown you are entering an = when you should not be, that causes : to be interpreted as a range delimiter.  Make sure the cell format in that case is the proper TIME format and then enter only the time, not prepended with =

Comment: Yes, the = sign appears AFTER I type. This happens in every cell. I never type an equal sign or a plus. In this case, I only typed 5:15 and the cell is already formatted to time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the Lotus Compatibility options are unchecked:

[image]

in Excel Options.

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't fix it.

Comment: Wait, the Lotus part is sheet specific.  Thank you!  This fixed it!!!!!

Comment: You know how `=Sum(1,2)` is the same as `+1+2`?  Isn't the `+` a holdover "function" from Lotus? Or is it a holdover from something much broader? (just curious)

Comment: @BruceWayne .............I am not sure ??

Comment: I searched around, and it seems like perhaps that's why: "The "+" character is a backwards-compatible effort by Microsoft to accommodate formula entry by people who were former Lotus users, in long ago days when Lotus was the dominant spreadsheet program and MS was building their customer base." (from [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/369789-why-do-some-people-use-plus-sign-beginning-formulas.html)).